# Git ignore file/dir in submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules

Can git be configured to ignore certain files/folders/paths that are within a submodule?

One of the submodules in my project (PHP) ships with a test directory including shell scripts and other potentially dangerous content, which I don't want to have on my Webserver.

Is there any configuration magic **within my main repo** to ignore `/modules/A/test/*`, so that these files will not be accessible after cloning/fetching/updating submodules?

*(Alternatively, having git add a static .htaccess file in the right location would be great, too)*

Comment: Submodules are their own separate repositories, so, no. Your best bet is to have some sort of deployment script that is not Git, but uses whatever is appropriate to extract the right commit(s) and/or file(s). It would be pretty trivial to have such a script write `.htaccess` files.

Comment: Bummer. My goal was to have a universal deployment script for each and all of my projects.

Comment: I just stumbled over [Ignoring files](https://help.github.com/articles/ignoring-files/) - It seems like we can ignore/exclude files globally on a machine. Not what I hoped for in terms of centralized configuration only in the main repo, but the next best option, I think.

Comment: As Vampire said, `.gitignore` won't help here either. You could have a committed file whose purpose is to act as directives to your deployment system, though. That would live in this main repo and hence not require submodules to conform to specific rules.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, even if `.gitignore` would take effect on submodules (it does not), `.gitignore` does not have any effect on already tracked files. It just tells Git to ignore files it does not yet track at all.