# Git: Ignore untracked files in submodule

Tags: git, git-submodules, gitignore

In my git repo, I have imported some other project as a submodule. So far, so good. However, the maintainers of the imported project are a bit sloppy about their `.gitignore` files. So, after building the imported project, `git status` (within the submodule) lists a ton of untracked files. And consequently, `git status` in my own project says:

```
modified:   <submodule> (untracked content)
```

My question is: Is there any way of telling `git` to ignore these untracked files without fixing the upstream `.gitignore` files?

---

I'm fully aware that the likely answer is "no", and I have seen [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/42860514/2445184) that tells me that it is not possible to ignore changes to tracked files. Which makes total sense to me, independent of the question whether the file is in a submodule or not. However, I'm only concerned with ignoring *untracked* files, so I think there is a slight chance that there is a good solution for my question.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**UPDATE** - In comments the question came up: can the parent repo automatically distribute these ignore rules.  If you use the original approach I suggest, the answer is "no" to the best of my knowledge.  However, under some circumstances there is a way to do it (from Роман Яковский's answer)...

---

The most flexible way would be to add ignore rules in the submodule's `gitdir`/info/exclude file.

```
cd path/to/parent/repo/.git/modules/module-name/info
vi exclude
```

add the pattern as it would appear in the submodule repo's `.gitignore` file.

You can confirm where the submodule's `gitdir` is by

```
cat path/to/parent/repo/submoduledir/.git
```

This lets you specify *exactly* what should be ignored; but the down side to this approach is that `gitdir`/info/exlcude is not propagated by push or fetch, so each repo must be individually configured.

If you don't need to be so selective about the files that are ignored - for example, if you can say "any worktree changes in the submodule should be ignored" - then you can specify an ignore rule in the module definition (.gitmodules), which of course is part of the committed work.  Possible ignore rules are explained in the gitmodules documentation: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules

Comment: Awesome, that will keep me happy. However, is there also a way to commit these excludes to the encompassing repo so that it will also keep my peers working on the same repo happy?

Comment: I don't think so. Rules that "ship" with the repo need to be in `.gitignore` files, and AFAIK `.gitignore` files in the parent repo can't set rules for paths that belong to the submodule.  So if fixing the submodule's `.gitignore` file isn't an option, then each clone of the parent repo probably has to be configured manually

Comment: Is this still true in 2023? Seems like this is a common problem that should have a solution with code reuse being so in vogue now.

Answer (score 7):

In `.gitmodules` add `ignore = all` to submodule.
There more options for `ignore`, you can read them in `git help config`, search `submodule.<name>.ignore`.

Comment: More options can be found here: https://git-scm.com/docs/gitmodules#Documentation/gitmodules.txt-submoduleltnamegtignore